# How can I calculate a fraction equation in Java as a Fraction?

Tags: java

An example of one of these equations could be '12/2 - 14/4'.

I need a method that can read the equation from a text file and can calculate the answer as a fraction. I need to be able to check if an input is the same as this answer, so I think outputting as a String is a way to go.

For more clarification: 
I am a Java beginner and my teacher has asked me to create a program which creates 30 random fractions and outputs them to a text file. The 'player' (as this is some sort of game) must guess the answer. They have two guesses before the game moves onto the next fraction.

I have the 30 random fractions generator working. Each fraction is on a separate line of the text file.

If anyone knows how to help it would be greatly appreciated as my class is online and I can't sit down with the teacher for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part.

Comment: This is probably a bit broad for Stack Overflow, because there are so many bits to this - parsing the expression, dealing with parentheses, turning a fraction into simplest form, adding fractions, subtracting fractions, multiplying fractions and dividing fractions.  You probably want to add these features one at a time, but this is a big project you've embarked on here.

Answer (score 0):

try Java FileReader Class and the `File.readLine()`-Method. Now you have to pass it to double with `double value = Double.parseDouble(text);`and calculate it. Before calculating you ought to split your String by e.g. "=" to seperate the result. After calculating you can compare the result and the String you read and return true or false.

Btw. don't use `String.equals()` to compare to values of numbers, because it compares the hash value of objects/variables and not the actual value.

Hope you can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions. This is something that allows you to use patterns in the string. For example:

```
    String equation = "12/2 - 14/4";
    String[] splitEq = equation.split(" "); //Splits using spaces
    for(String str : splitEq) {
        if (str.matches("\\d+/\\d+")) { //Uses a regex, "\\d+/\\d+" that represents at least one digit followed by a "/" followed by at least on digit
            String[] fraction = str.split("/");
        }
    }
```

Allows you to separate out the fractions from the mathematical operator (assuming it is all separated by spaces), then allows you to obtain the numbers that make up the fractions, in String[] fraction.

The mathematical operator will be the second element in the String[] splitEq.